# Append pairwise distances to dataframe without missmatch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`. `df1` consists of vectors of length 26 and `df2` consists of both vectors of length 26 and unique `id`s. I provide dictionaries at the end of the question.

So, `df1` is of the type:

```
vec1
1623       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
832   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.83, 6.47, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0, 15.0, 14.0, 10.44, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

and `df2` is given by:

```
                      id  \
774    A4060454751516272   
6570   A4060463723916275   
11466  A4060454576016272   
7394   A4050494816516277   

                                                                                                                                         vec2  
774      [2.0, 14.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 14.0]  
6570     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 15.5, 6.0, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
11466  [0.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 12.0, 15.0, 16.0]  
7394    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 4.0, 6.0, 15.0, 15.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

What I want to do is to compute the distances (custom distance) between all vectors in `df1` and all vectors in `df2`, so there are 8 distances. To do so, I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

def custom_distance(x,y):
    d = np.count_nonzero(x)
    dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((x - y)**2/d))
    return dist

Ax =  df1['vec1'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
Bx =  df2['vec2'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))

A = Ax.to_numpy()
B = Bx.to_numpy()
AA = np.stack(A)
BB = np.stack(B)

result = pairwise_distances(AA, BB, metric=custom_distance, n_jobs=-1)
```

which gives:

```
result = array([[14.91852875, 12.57726123, 16.76491873, 11.1383347 ],
       [12.74197493,  4.58371301, 13.84225144,  9.21726234]])
```

**My Problem**

I actually want these distance as a column in the dataframe:

```
                                                                                                                                      vec1  \
0       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
1       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
2       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
3       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5, 0.0, 8.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
4  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.83, 6.47, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0, 15.0, 14.0, 10.44, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
5  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.83, 6.47, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0, 15.0, 14.0, 10.44, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
6  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.83, 6.47, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0, 15.0, 14.0, 10.44, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   
7  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.83, 6.47, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0, 15.0, 14.0, 10.44, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]   

                  id  \
0  A4060454751516272   
1  A4060463723916275   
2  A4060454576016272   
3  A4050494816516277   
4  A4060454751516272   
5  A4060463723916275   
6  A4060454576016272   
7  A4050494816516277   

                                                                                                                                     vec2  
0    [2.0, 14.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 14.0]  
1    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 15.5, 6.0, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
2  [0.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 12.0, 15.0, 16.0]  
3   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 4.0, 6.0, 15.0, 15.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
4    [2.0, 14.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 2.0, 14.0]  
5    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 15.5, 6.0, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
6  [0.0, 9.0, 7.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 12.0, 15.0, 16.0]  
7   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 4.0, 6.0, 15.0, 15.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

which is the dataframe of all combinations of vectors in `df1` and `df2`. I could append `result` to that dataframe but I am unsure whether there can be missmatches (e.g., distance x between two vectors is actually the distance between two other vectors.

Greatful for any insight!

**Data**

```
df1 = {'vec1': {1623: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   1.5,
   0.0,
   8.0,
   13.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   5.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  832: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   2.83,
   6.47,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   0.0,
   7.0,
   15.0,
   14.0,
   10.44,
   2.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0]}}
```

and

```
df2 = {'id': {774: 'A4060454751516272',
  6570: 'A4060463723916275',
  11466: 'A4060454576016272',
  7394: 'A4050494816516277'},
 'vec2': {774: [2.0,
   14.0,
   9.0,
   8.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   6.0,
   2.0,
   14.0],
  6570: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   12.0,
   15.5,
   6.0,
   3.5,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0],
  11466: [0.0,
   9.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   10.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   3.0,
   12.0,
   15.0,
   16.0],
  7394: [0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   11.0,
   0.0,
   4.0,
   6.0,
   15.0,
   15.0,
   7.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0,
   0.0]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity let's work with vector indices. Note that df1, df2 are dictionaries, let's create small dataframes with vector indices and ids(where available), and then, **importantly**, merge them using 'cross' method:

```
dfi1 = pd.DataFrame(df1).reset_index()[['index']]
dfi2 = pd.DataFrame(df2).reset_index()[['index', 'id']]
dfm = dfi1.merge(dfi2, how = 'cross')
```

`dfm` looks like this:

```
      index_x    index_y  id
--  ---------  ---------  -----------------
 0        832        774  A4060454751516272
 1        832       6570  A4060463723916275
 2        832      11466  A4060454576016272
 3        832       7394  A4050494816516277
 4       1623        774  A4060454751516272
 5       1623       6570  A4060463723916275
 6       1623      11466  A4060454576016272
 7       1623       7394  A4050494816516277
```

Now we can apply `custom_distance` to pairs of vectors as indexed by `index_x` and `index_y`

```
dfm['dist'] = dfm.apply(
    lambda r: custom_distance(np.array(df1['vec1'][r['index_x']]) ,
    np.array(df2['vec2'][r['index_y']]) ), axis=1
    )
```

Now `dfm` looks like this:

```
      index_x    index_y  id                     dist
--  ---------  ---------  -----------------  --------
 0        832        774  A4060454751516272  12.742
 1        832       6570  A4060463723916275   4.58371
 2        832      11466  A4060454576016272  13.8423
 3        832       7394  A4050494816516277   9.21726
 4       1623        774  A4060454751516272  14.9185
 5       1623       6570  A4060463723916275  12.5773
 6       1623      11466  A4060454576016272  16.7649
 7       1623       7394  A4050494816516277  11.1383
```

If you want to put the vectors into the same dataframe you can then do:

```
dfm['vec1'] = dfm['index_x'].map(df1['vec1'])
dfm['vec2'] = dfm['index_y'].map(df2['vec2'])
dfm.drop(columns = ['index_x', 'index_y'])
```